# C client for socket.io

Tags: c, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to establish a connection from a program in C to a node server with socket.io.

The only way I could figure out was to make http request from the C program to the node server so I have dis part a little covered.

Now I need to receive some information from the node server from the C program.

Is there any client library for c that lets me do this?
In case it does not exist, could you gime me some ideas to make it work?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you want to use HTTP or websockets?

Comment: I want to use websockets, but Im currently using http to fire some events on the node server.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try cellophane.io:

https://github.com/ikeralbeniz/cellophane.io

it is still buggy so it is only fot testing or POCs..

Answer (score 1):

New C++ Client

Based on Boost and WebSocket++, this full-featured Socket.IO 1.0 client has the fundamental advantage of working on multiple platforms.

http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-cpp/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a library and examples try [libwebsockets](http://git.warmcat.com/cgi-bin/cgit/libwebsockets/)

It has both client and server capability and I hope it should help you out well with its documentations and examples.

Comment: Note that this library is licensed under GPLv2.  You should only use it or look at its code if you're prepared to license your code as GPL also.

Comment: As of Feb 2013 at the latest, LWS is licensed under LGPL v2.1, with an additional exception that says static linking does not count as a derivative work.  You can safely link non-GPL code against it, statically or dynamically.  https://libwebsockets.org/git/libwebsockets/tree/LICENSE

Comment: For libwebsockets, LGPL v2 with static linking exception, If I modify libwebsockets's example source code to adapt to my application. Does not mean I have to open source my application too ? or I have to write one from scratch ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use C++ instead? If so,

https://github.com/ebshimizu/socket.io-clientpp